# How do I count same values in an multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here I have an array. This is it:

```
Array ( Array (
     'name' => 'bmw',
     'id' => 1
 ), Array (
     'name' => 'toyota',
     'id' => 1
 ),Array ( 
     'name' => 'tata',
     'id' => 2 
 ),Array ( 
     'name' => 'bajaj',
     'id' => 3
 ),Array (
     'name' => 'kawasaki',
     'id' => 3
 ), Array (
     'name' => 'tvs',
     'id' => 3
 ),Array (
     'name' => 'mitsubishi',
     'id' => 2
 )
);
```

and what code should be next to give me result as id 1 => 2 items , id 2 => 2 items and id 3 => 3 items?
I tried `array_count_values()` and it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation `array_count_values` works only on strings and integers. You can use it but first you should extract a column with ids. As of PHP 5.5 it's really easy, just call a function called  [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

```
$list = array ( Array (
     'name' => 'bmw',
     'id' => 1
 ), Array (
     'name' => 'toyota',
     'id' => 1
 ),Array ( 
     'name' => 'tata',
     'id' => 2 
 ),Array ( 
     'name' => 'bajaj',
     'id' => 3
 ),Array (
     'name' => 'kawasaki',
     'id' => 3
 ), Array (
     'name' => 'tvs',
     'id' => 3
 ),Array (
     'name' => 'mitsubishi',
     'id' => 2
 )
);

$results = array_count_values(array_column($list, 'id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a nicer solution, but this should work.

Assuming that your array is saved in `$arr`.

```
$countItemsById = [];

foreach( $arr as $data ){
  $countItemsById[ $data['id'] ]++;
}
```

This code does the following:
First it is creating a new Array `$countItemsById`.
After that it loops trough your existing array and increases the value in the new array by 1 for the `index (key)` that has the value of the id.

After that, `$countItemsById` will look like this:

```
Array (1 => 2, 2 => 2, 3 => 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

loop your array, to calculate the occerence for each id.

```
<?php
$list = array ( Array (
     'name' => 'bmw',
     'id' => 1
 ), Array (
     'name' => 'toyota',
     'id' => 1
 ),Array (
     'name' => 'tata',
     'id' => 2
 ),Array (
     'name' => 'bajaj',
     'id' => 3
 ),Array (
     'name' => 'kawasaki',
     'id' => 3
 ), Array (
     'name' => 'tvs',
     'id' => 3
 ),Array (
     'name' => 'mitsubishi',
     'id' => 2
 )
);

$results = [];
array_walk($list, function($v) use(&$results){
  $results[$v['id']]++;
});
var_dump($results);
```

output:

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(2)
  [3]=>
  int(3)
}
```